# Create Postgis GEOM from OSM bounding box

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to use the data that is retuned from the nomatim API to perform a simple geospatial search. The users search for a place, i.e Leeds, and this returns simple info, including the following bounding box:

```
"boundingbox": [
      "53.6983747",
      "53.9458558",
      "-1.8004213",
      "-1.2903452"
 ],
```

Using this, I should be able to create a bounding box using the Postgis function:

```
geometry ST_MakeEnvelope(double precision xmin, double precision ymin, double precision xmax, double precision ymax, integer srid=unknown);
```

However, when I do this, I am unable to get correct geometries that I can then use, and plug into another function wherein I check if a point is within that geometry.

As far as I can tell, the SRID for the OSM data is 3857. When I perform the following:

```
ST_MakeEnvelope(53.6983747,-1.8004213,53.9458558,-1.2903452, 3857);
```

And then perform a search on this, I have to add 500000 metres to the ST_DWithin to be able to get a point which is right in the centre.

Does anyone know If there is a better way to approach this, or spot any mistakes in this? I have tried a couple different approaches and I cannot find any more accurate than this one.

For reference, this is the search I've been performing:

```
Select * from geometries 
where ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(geom,27700),ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.546033, 53.798075),3857),27700), 70)
```

at 75 I get the Newcastle box, and at 80 I get the Leeds box, and that point is in Leeds. I am very confused.

Comment: Osm data are in EPSG:4326.

Comment: 3857 is spherical mercator, as used by Google Maps to render tiles. Your coordinates are lat/long which is 4326, which is typically used for vector overlays, as it corresponds to what you get from a GPS anywhere on the  globe, even GeordieLandia :-)

Comment: I have changed over to 4326 - Thank you! but I still get issues with the geoms created by the envelopes

Comment: Edit your question and describe your current issues.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, SRID of OSM data must be 4326.
And then you're confusing x (=lon) and y (=lat).

OSM returns:

```
"boundingbox": [
      ymin,
      ymax,
      xmin,
      xmax
 ]
```

So your query must look like this:

```
ST_MakeEnvelope(-1.8004213,53.6983747,-1.2903452,53.9458558, 4326);
```